# Django request.session not working properly

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, web

i am creating a web app and i'm using ajax to send the data from frontend to backend so i can process the forms and save them to the database. I send the data from ajax to a get-data method and from there i save it to the session, and when i access the /success page and try to get the same data from session, it tells me that the key doesn't exist. How is that possible? Here is the code down below.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/get-data/",
      data: JSON.stringify(obj),
      dataType: "text",
      headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log("success"); // i get this, so i it means that the ajax works properly.
      },
      error: function (response, err, err2) {
        console.log(err2);
      },
    });
```

```
def get_data(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if is_ajax(request):
            rec_data = json.loads(request.body)
            print("the request came")
            request.session["data_check_form"] = rec_data
            print("everything set")
            print(request.session["data_check_form"])  # i print this and i get the json file properly
            return JsonResponse({"success": "200"})
```

```
def success_view(request):
    print("test")
    data = request.session.get("data_check_form", False) 
    print(data) # i get false
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `request.session.modified = True` after any changes in `session` as

```
def get_data(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if is_ajax(request):
            rec_data = json.loads(request.body)
            print("the request came")
            request.session["data_check_form"] = rec_data
            request.session.modified = True
            print("everything set")
            print(request.session["data_check_form"])  # i print this and i get the json file properly
            return JsonResponse({"success": "200"})
```

Or you can set `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` to `True` in `settings.py` which will save session to database on every single request as stated

> To change this default behavior, set the SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST setting to True. When set to True, Django will save the session to the database on every single request.

Comment: I tried it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Also you cant set `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST =True` in `settings.py`

Comment: I tried that as well and still get the same error.

Comment: Can you share your print `rec_data` what you obtained?

Comment: Yeah, in get_data() i saved rec_data to session and then printed it. I got the result but when i printed the request.session["data_check_form"] from success_view() it acted like that key doesn't even exist in the session.

Comment: {'name1': 'test_name', 'last_name1': 'test_lastname', 'email1': 'test_email', 'street_number1': 'test_street', 'city1': 'test_city', 'phone_number1': '7869756856', 'postal_number1': 'test_postnum', 'country1': 'test_country', 'pers_text1': ' '}

Comment: Have you tried `request.session.save()` after `request.session.modified = True`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241533/discussion-between-user8193706-and-thuggytm).